# In views how to merge two columns?

Tags: views

I am using Views to display submitted contents as table and I need to merge two columns ("Uploaded covering letter" and "Uploaded e-book") into one.

[image: screenshot]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first need to add one more field in your view i.e **Global Custom Text**.

After that you need to merge your two fields result in this field output using **Replacement patterns**

As in attached screenshot, I am merging *nid* and *first name* field in global custom text field output.

You also need to exclude "Uploaded covering letter" and "Uploaded e-book" field from output using **Exclude from display** attribute. You need to checked this check box for both the fields. [image]

Comment: Thank you Pushpinder, thanks a lot. This works for me :)

Comment: +1. Thankyou. I had to merge 3 columns and this worked.